# BlackScreen with power square flashing

Tags: video

Here's the problem. I can flash a new image using Noobs and with the same powersupply I can boot in graphical mode without problem. When I flash an image for work, I only see a black screen with the multicolor square flashing up on the top right corner of the hdmi display or rca display.

The device is initially configured to run with a LCD Display but as I see the square on any other display that I connect, I have the feeling that video output is actually detected (could be the gpu broadcasting on any interface).

The thing is that during the boot phase, I don't see anything either. Usually we would see the pi logo with some boot logs but with that image it's completely black.

I have the feeling like the PI is trying to output to a the LCD that isn't connected... Any idea how to disable the video port and force hdmi?

Writing "hdmi_force_hotplug=1" in boot/config.txt doesn't seems to help.

Comment: a small rainbow icon in the upper right indicates insufficient voltage. Changing the powersupply/cable may solve the problem.

Comment: @SteveRobillard I'm aware of that. It's not the issue here.

Comment: As far as I know that is the only reason for that icon.

Comment: @SteveRobillard I'm not worried about the icon, I'm worried that I only see that Icon and nothing else.

Comment: Have you considered that under volting the Pi is the cause of the problem?

Comment: @SteveRobillard no because as I explained in the question, the device works well with a different image with the same power supply. And since it outputs the icon to the hdmi port, it should output an image.